# simplemodal contact form. Some fields not getting emailed

Tags: php, simplemodal

I'm trying to add a couple of fields to the simplemodal contact form (not the Wordpress plugin) and it's not emailing two of the fields "Name" and "Company".  The rest are coming through.  My PHP file is below.  I've been at it for ages and can't work out where it's going wrong.  Help would be really appreciated as I'm a bit of a novice.

```
<?php

/*
 * SimpleModal Contact Form
 * http://simplemodal.com
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Eric Martin - http://ericmmartin.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

// User settings
$to = "info@myemail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";

// Include extra form fields and/or submitter data?
// false = do not include
$extra = array(
    "form_subject"  => true,
    "form_cc"       => true,
    "ip"            => false,
    "user_agent"    => false

);

// Process
$action = isset($_POST["action"]) ? $_POST["action"] : "";
if (empty($action)) {
    // Send back the contact form HTML
    $output = "<div style='display:none'>
    <div class='contact-top'></div>
    <div class='contact-content'>
        <h1 class='contact-title'>Send us a message:</h1>
        <div class='contact-loading' style='display:none'></div>
        <div class='contact-message' style='display:none'></div>
        <form action='#' style='display:none'>
            <label for='contact-name'>*Name:</label>
            <input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='name' tabindex='1001' />


<label for='contact-company'>*Company:</label>
            <input type='text' id='contact-company' class='contact-input' name='company' tabindex='1002' /> 

<label for='contact-phone'>*Phone:</label>
            <input type='text' id='contact-phone' class='contact-input' name='phone' tabindex='1003' />     



            <label for='contact-email'>*Email:</label>
            <input type='text' id='contact-email' class='contact-input' name='email' tabindex='1004' />"
;
    if ($extra["form_subject"]) {
        $output .= "
            <label for='contact-subject'>Subject:</label>
            <input type='text' id='contact-subject' class='contact-input' name='subject' value='' tabindex='1005' />";
    }

    $output .= "
            <label for='contact-message'>*Message:</label>
            <textarea id='contact-message' class='contact-input' name='message' cols='30' rows='4' tabindex='1006'></textarea>
            <br/>";

    if ($extra["form_cc"]) {
        $output .= "
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type='checkbox' id='contact-cc' name='cc' value='1' tabindex='1007' /> <span class='contact-cc'>Send me a copy</span>
            <br/>";
    }

    $output .= "
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <button type='submit' class='contact-send contact-button' tabindex='1008'>Send</button>
            <button type='submit' class='contact-cancel contact-button simplemodal-close' tabindex='1009'>Cancel</button>
            <br/>
            <input type='hidden' name='token' value='" . smcf_token($to) . "'/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class='contact-bottom'><a href='http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/'>Powered by SimpleModal</a></div>";

    echo $output;
}
else if ($action == "send") {
    // Send the email
    $name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : "";
    $company = isset($_POST["company"]) ? $_POST["company"] : "";
    $phone = isset($_POST["phone"]) ? $_POST["phone"] : "";
    $email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
    $subject = isset($_POST["subject"]) ? $_POST["subject"] : $subject;
    $message = isset($_POST["message"]) ? $_POST["message"] : "";
    $cc = isset($_POST["cc"]) ? $_POST["cc"] : "";
    $token = isset($_POST["token"]) ? $_POST["token"] : "";

    // make sure the token matches
    if ($token === smcf_token($to)) {
        smcf_send($name, $company, $phone, $email, $subject, $message, $cc);
        echo "Your message was successfully sent.";
    }
    else {
        echo "Unfortunately, your message could not be verified.";
    }
}

function smcf_token($s) {
    return md5("smcf-" . $s . date("WY"));
}

// Validate and send email
function smcf_send($name, $company, $phone, $email, $subject, $message, $cc) {
    global $to, $extra;

    // Filter and validate fields
    $name = smcf_filter($name);
    $company = smcf_filter($company);
    $phone = smcf_filter($phone);
    $subject = smcf_filter($subject);
    $email = smcf_filter($email);
    if (!smcf_validate_email($email)) {
        $subject .= " - invalid email";
        $message .= "\n\nBad email: $email";
        $email = $to;
        $cc = 0; // do not CC "sender"
    }

    // Add additional info to the message
    if ($extra["ip"]) {
        $message .= "\n\nIP: " . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
    if ($extra["user_agent"]) {
        $message .= "\n\nUSER AGENT: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
    }

    // Set and wordwrap message body
    $body = "From: $name\n\n";
    $body = "Company: $company\n\n";
    $body = "Phone: $phone\n\n";
    $body .= "Message: $message";
    $body = wordwrap($body, 70);

    // Build header
    $headers = "From: $email\n";
    if ($cc == 1) {
        $headers .= "Cc: $email\n";
    }
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/SimpleModalContactForm";

    // UTF-8
    if (function_exists('mb_encode_mimeheader')) {
        $subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subject, "UTF-8", "B", "\n");
    }
    else {
        // you need to enable mb_encode_mimeheader or risk 
        // getting emails that are not UTF-8 encoded
    }
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n";

    // Send email
    @mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) or 
        die("Unfortunately, a server issue prevented delivery of your message.");
}

// Remove any un-safe values to prevent email injection
function smcf_filter($value) {
    $pattern = array("/\n/","/\r/","/content-type:/i","/to:/i", "/from:/i", "/cc:/i");
    $value = preg_replace($pattern, "", $value);
    return $value;
}

// Validate email address format in case client-side validation "fails"
function smcf_validate_email($email) {
    $at = strrpos($email, "@");

    // Make sure the at (@) sybmol exists and  
    // it is not the first or last character
    if ($at && ($at < 1 || ($at + 1) == strlen($email)))
        return false;

    // Make sure there aren't multiple periods together
    if (preg_match("/(\.{2,})/", $email))
        return false;

    // Break up the local and domain portions
    $local = substr($email, 0, $at);
    $domain = substr($email, $at + 1);


    // Check lengths
    $locLen = strlen($local);
    $domLen = strlen($domain);
    if ($locLen < 1 || $locLen > 64 || $domLen < 4 || $domLen > 255)
        return false;

    // Make sure local and domain don't start with or end with a period
    if (preg_match("/(^\.|\.$)/", $local) || preg_match("/(^\.|\.$)/", $domain))
        return false;

    // Check for quoted-string addresses
    // Since almost anything is allowed in a quoted-string address,
    // we're just going to let them go through
    if (!preg_match('/^"(.+)"$/', $local)) {
        // It's a dot-string address...check for valid characters
        if (!preg_match('/^[-a-zA-Z0-9!#$%*\/?|^{}`~&\'+=_\.]*$/', $local))
            return false;
    }

    // Make sure domain contains only valid characters and at least one period
    if (!preg_match("/^[-a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$/", $domain) || !strpos($domain, "."))
        return false;   

    return true;
}

exit;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is where you create the body of the message. You aren't using the concatenate operator (a period .) before the equals sign. Without it, you lose everything you previously assigned to that variable. Here's what your code should look like:

```
// Set and wordwrap message body
$body = "From: $name\n\n";
$body .= "Company: $company\n\n";
$body .= "Phone: $phone\n\n";
$body .= "Message: $message";
$body = wordwrap($body, 70);
```

There are two additional things you should do:

1. Add a `method='post'` to the form tag.
2. Provide both name and value attributes to the submit button.  You check for "action" in the script, but it's not defined anywhere. Add `name="action" value="send"` to the send button
   .

---